Why can't I send `<C-@>` to terminal job?
In a regular bash terminal, I can send the <C-@> (null character) by Ctrl+Space. I can see that by invoking cat, and sending <C-@> yields:
^@

However, when I do this in Vim terminal, nothing gets sent, but sometimes I see the terminal refreshing. Why is this, and can I make the Vim terminal behave the same as the regular terminal?
